# popup window not opening on button click in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, popup

I have sample asp.net button for which i am writing click event and trying to open a new popupwindow , for some reason the popup window is not opening , please can i know whether the issue is related with browser or code

Test.aspx

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        function openNewWin(url) {

            var x = window.open(url, 'mynewwin', 'width=600,height=600,toolbar=1');

            x.focus();

        }

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
     <asp:Button ID="btnOpenPop" runat="server" Text="Open Pop"           

        onclick="btnOpenPop_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Test.cs

```
public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }

        protected void btnOpenPop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string url = "http://www.dotnetcurry.com";

             ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "OpenWin", "<script>openNewWin('" + url + "')</script>");




        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using FireBug to inspect/debug the code or an error console to see what's going wrong?

Comment: ya i inspected, control reaches javascript openNewWin function , but i dont see any errors

Comment: Are you sure that you actually reach that line? Open the console and enter: window.open('http:// www.dotnetcurry.com', 'MyWindow', 'width=600,height=600,toolbar=1'); That will work. Again, have tried adding a semicolon to the end of the function call? And btw, what's your browser?

Comment: also, to make sure you enter that js function, you could try to alert something at the beginning, prefferably the url you try to open. Maybe the URL is not valid.

Comment: also (sorry to spam you with comments), you could inspect the rendered HTML to see if the registered script is actually in your page. As far as I know, it should be somewhere at the end of the page, before the <body> tag closes.

Comment: I have directly added window.open('http:// www.dotnetcurry.com', 'MyWindow', 'width=600,height=600,toolbar=1');  still the window is not opening

Comment: then it's a browser issue, maybe you have a popup blocker. i am not familiar with safari at all.

Comment: Finally it worked after adding btnOpenPop.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:window.open('www.microsoft.com'); return false;"); In the pageload function :)

Comment: That's strange, everything worked for me in Chrome (which also uses WebKit), i just opened console and entered window.open('http:// www.dotnetcurry.com', 'MyWindow', 'width=600,height=600,toolbar=1');

Answer (score 3):

RegisterStartupScript is for registering a script that is supposed to run on page load(client side). Use RegisterClientScript instead.

But why would you want to do a postback to run a javascript function? Instead of trying to execute the code server-side do it client-side:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnOpenPop" runat="server" Text="Open Pop" OnClientClick="openNewWin(<%= URL %>)" />
```

and declare the URL as a property in your class:

```
public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string URL {get;set;}
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the reason i am trying to do from serverside is i want to attach some runtime captured values to url parameter

Comment: Didn't get it, what's wrong with using RegisterStartupScript in this case? The intention was to open a popup after page would reload after button-click, wasn't it?

Comment: @ArturUdod, yes, you are right, it should work with RegisterStartupScript too.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried adding a semicolon after `openNewWin` call? Like this

```
"<script>openNewWin('" + url + "');</script>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this Javascript in the Head

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            function popup(url) {
                var width = 600;
                var height = 600;
                var left = (screen.width - width) / 2;
                var top = (screen.height - height) / 2;
                var params = 'width=' + width + ', height=' + height;
                params += ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left;
                params += ', toolbar=no';
                params += ', menubar=no';
                params += ', resizable=yes';
                params += ', directories=no';
                params += ', scrollbars=no';
                params += ', status=no';
                params += ', location=no';
                newwin = window.open(url, 'd', params);
                if (window.focus) {
                    newwin.focus()
                }
                return false;
            }     
        </script>
```

Now call this on the buttone click

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" 
             OnClientClick="popup('addNewClients.aspx');" 
             Text="Add New Clients" />
```

Answer (score 0):

use ScriptManger

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "", "<script>$(function () {$('#popupID').modal({show:true,keyboard: false, backdrop: 'static'});});</script>", false);
```

Answer (score -2):

Use jquery for popup window as,

```
$('#btnOpenPop).bind('click',function() { 

var x = window.open(url, 'mynewwin', 'width=600,height=600,toolbar=1'); 

 x.focus(); 

});
```